# If a odom frame is useless as a global reference then what should be considered?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According [this](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#coordinate-frames) explanation, if Odom frame is useless as a global reference then what should be considered?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306802/if-a-odom-frame-is-useless-as-a-global-reference-then-what-should-be-considered?/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When it's said that `odom` is useless as global frame it's because of the drifts. If your robot drifts then odom will know that you drifted but since `odom`is your global frame then "all your world have drifted" too. It's just a problem of frame of reference.

That's why the frame `map` is used as global frame. Each drift caught by `odom` is sent to `map` thanks to `tf` and the transform between `map` and `odom` will tell you how the robot drifted so you will know where you actually are.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-10-26**:
Thank you for your response. I have a subquestion. I had [posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306389/how-to-check-if-there-is-problem-in-odometry/) this question, the tilt in the figure is due to drift in robot? as you are saying the world gets drifted. Is it due to that? Let me know. Thanks.